# Select text, right-click and have option to append text to an URL in a new tab?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

I use PC Chrome.

We use two ticketing systems where I work: Salesforce and JIRA. Tickets cross reference each other, but the reference ids are not clickable (are not hyperlinks to the other tool) -- only text.

While others work mostly in one tool or the other, my team uses both heavily. I'm seeking a way to make moving between the tools easier.

My first idea:

***How can I select the id (text), right-click on the selected, and have an option to open in a new tab. The new tab would go to an URL consisting of some hardcoded string (link to the other tool) + the selected text appended. I would have two of these (one for "each direction").***

`http://<linkToTool>/<appendedId>`

I would have two of these (one for each "direction").

How would I do this? I have searched around, but maybe am not using the correct terminology.

Or maybe there is a better solution?

I found this for Mac + keyboard shortcuts : [Shortcut to open new tab with selected text in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/383904/shortcut-to-open-new-tab-with-selected-text-in-chrome)

(I'm only a user of the tools and can't change them. My only influence is via opening a help desk ticket to our tools team.)

Answer (score 1):

You can consider having two bookmarklets to have a selected TicketId sent to either of two domains.

A [Bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2010/07/joy-of-bookmarklets.html) is a small JavaScript program that can be hosted on the browser's bookmarks bar and used to simplify a multi-step or repetitive activity by automating it.

Adapt the below bookmarklet code for your requirement:

```
javascript:(function(){window.open("http://example.com/?id="+window.getSelection().toString())})();
```

`window.getSelection().toString()` can get the text you've selected. This is appended to the tool's URL. `window.open` method will open the dynamically generated URL in a new window.

To put the bookmarklet in action, select text and then click on the bookmarklet to have the desired ticket opened for you in a new window via a dynamically generated URL.

[This Dictionary Bookmarklet](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/01/dictionary-bookmarklet.html) follows a similar idea.